# Sending email from website frontpage Odoo v9 community

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-9

I know this might seem odd

But is there a way to send an email with a specific template from a website module in Odoo ?

I mean, suppose I have a button on website, this button should call for a template on backend and send the email automatically.

Any example of this I should look for?

I've looked for `website_crm` , `website_form` and `website_blog` but I don't see any example like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    @api.model
    def send_mail_function(self):
        template_id = self.env.ref('custom_crm.mail_template_id')
        if template_id:
           template_id.send_mail(self.id, force_send=True)
        return True
```